# Save NSMutable dictionary data in plist file _ integers as key

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I'm currently trying to save a NSMutabledictionary keys and objects in a plist file. My keys are integers, so I'm using NSNumber to put them into the writeToFile function.

Even with that change, I cant find any of my saved data in the plist find. I suppose there is a problem with the NSNumber pointer because when I use a string it works.

do you have an idea of what is missing in my code?

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionnaireNoms = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:40];
    NSNumber *nombre = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:dictionnaireNoms.count];        
    NSString *nomCommerce = text.text;
    [dictionnaireNoms setObject:nomCommerce forKey:nombre];

    //2. Sauvegarde du nom dans un fichier
    [saveDicoCommerce enregisterNom:dictionnaireNoms];


- (void)enregisterNom:(NSMutableDictionary*)nom
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", documentsDirectory);
    NSString *pathNom = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NomsDeCommerces.plist"];
    if (!documentsDirectory) {
        NSLog(@"Documents directory not found!");
        return;
    }
    [nom writeToFile:pathNom atomically:YES];
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathNom])
    {
        NSLog(@"file not found");
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: it is not possible as only * object type data can be saved to nsdictionary

Comment: Thanks. Does it means that it is impossible to set integers as keys with NSMutableDictionary (using other classes for example)?

Comment: Because I found in the writeToFile:Atomically method of NSMutableDictionary that:  "This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary) before writing out the file, and returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the resultant file would not be a valid property list".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDictionary` can only write itself directly if it only contains string keys.  It confirms this you try to write using

```
[[NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:nom format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:nil] writeToFile:pathNom atomically:NO];`
```

The output is:

> Property list invalid for format: 200 (property list dictionaries may only have keys which are CFStrings, not 'CFNumber')

However, you can store `NSDictionary` objects containing `NSNumber` keys if you serialize it using `NSCoding`.  Replace this:

```
[nom writeToFile:pathNom atomically:YES];
```

with:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:nom toFile:pathNom];
```

To read the file created, use:

```
NSDictionary *nom2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:pathNom];
```

For more information about archives, see the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i).

Answer (score 0):

Why do u want to allocate NSNumber? Try this [your_dictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:your_int]];